# No protocol exception when reading a URL

Tags: java

I am trying to read a URL and then convert it to a string and write the content to a text file, but I get the following exception when I compile the code. Here is my code and my exception:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Main {
public  static  String url = "google.com";
public  static  String fileName= null;
public  static  String fileConttent ="Something";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      getText(new String(url));
}

public static void getText(String url) throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL("url\n" +
            "    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {\n" +
            "          getText(new String(url));\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    public static void getText(String url) throws Exception {\n" +
            "        URL website = new URL(\"url");
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        response.append(inputLine);

    in.close();

    String toBeWritten = response.toString();
    System.out.println(toBeWritten);
}




public static void createFile(String fileName,String fileContent){
    Writer writer = null;

    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Documents\\t"+"fileName"), "utf-8"));
        writer.write(fileContent);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // report
    } finally {
        try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
    }

}



}
```

This is my exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: url
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
at Main.getText(Main.java:15)
at Main.main(Main.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

What should be done to solve the issue? Thanks for all answers in advance.

**Update**

Thank you so much for your answer. I did what you said but I still get the same error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: url
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      getText(new String(url));
}

public static void getText(String url) throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL("url
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
at Main.getText(Main.java:15)
at Main.main(Main.java:11)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: It's really good practice to learn to read stack traces. The compiler usually tells you the line number where the code failed (or close to it).

Comment: @Israel If you have solved the problem, could you post an answer explaining what the solution is?

Answer (score 3):

`public  static  String url = "google.com";`

That's a domain, not a URL (or a relative URL for a file named "google.com," but let's not go there). URLs have protocols, e.g. http.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the protocol to your url:

```
public  static  String url = "http://google.com";
```

And you have to chnage your code (What ever the result should be):

```
URL website = new URL("url\n" +
            "    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {\n" +
            "          getText(new String(url));\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    public static void getText(String url) throws Exception {\n" +
            "        URL website = new URL(\"url");
```

to

```
URL website = new URL(url);
```

Comment: @IsraelCohen i have changed my answer.

Comment: The problem was with this part:

Comment: "url\n" +
            "    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {\n" +
            "          getText(new String(url));\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    public static void getText(String url) throws Exception {\n" +
            "        URL website = new URL(\"url");

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Main {
 public static String url = "https://www.google.com";
 public static String fileName = null;
 public static String fileConttent = "Something";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  getText(new String(url));
 }

 public static void getText(String url) throws Exception {
  URL website = new URL(url);
  URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    connection.getInputStream()));

  StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
  String inputLine;

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
   response.append(inputLine);

  in.close();

  String toBeWritten = response.toString();
  System.out.println(toBeWritten);
 }
}
```